# How to set a default time in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I created a Django ModelForm.

Here is the models.py file

```
class Room(models. Model):
    available_from = models.TimeField()
    available_till = models.TimeField()
```

Here is the forms.py file

```
class RoomForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class TimeInput(forms.TimeInput):
        input_type = 'time'

    available_from = forms.TimeField(
        widget=TimeInput(),
        )

    available_till = forms.TimeField(
        widget=TimeInput(),
        )


    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['available_from','available_till']
```

I want to know how to set a default time to the form.

Comment: Set the default to *what*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Let us say, 02:00 AM. I just want to know the format so that I can change it later on also, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a default in the model if you want to do this for all forms/admins/… that are derived from this model:

```
from datetime import time


class Room(models. Model):
    available_from = models.TimeField(default=time(2))
    available_till = models.TimeField()
```

or if this is specific to this form, you can use the [**`initial=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#initial):

```
from datetime import time


class TimeInput(forms.TimeInput):
    input_type = 'time'

class RoomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    available_from = forms.TimeField(
        widget=TimeInput(),
        initial=time(2)
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['available_from','available_till']
        widgets = {'available_till': TimeInput}
```